# Pandas Concat: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `concat` some `timeseries`. For some datasets this works. My `timeseries` uses the `date` as the index. Now for a few datasets where the `ts.size` are the same, the `pd.concat` works perfectly. But when the `size` is different among the `timeseries` I get the error: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. So I assume this happens due to the difference in `size`. If so, should I pad the `timeseries` with zeros?

`ts.head()`:

```
date
2017-03-09    24.6245
2017-03-10    24.5765
2017-03-13    24.5767
2017-03-14    24.5344
2017-03-15    24.5440
```

I have been stuck on this for a day so any help is appreciated. Thanks
Here is the original question I posted and you can see my code: [ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871353/valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-pandas/45871411?noredirect=1#comment78727889_45871411). I just want to know if this is problem.

My Code:

```
def get_adj_nav(self, fund_id):
    df_nav = read_frame(
        super(__class__, self).filter(fund__id=fund_id, nav__gt=0).exclude(fund__account_class=0).order_by(
            'valuation_period_end_date'), coerce_float=True,
        fieldnames=['income_payable', 'valuation_period_end_date', 'nav', 'outstanding_shares_par'],
        index_col='valuation_period_end_date')
    df_dvd, skip = self.get_dvd(fund_id=fund_id)
    df_nav_adj = calculate_adjusted_prices(
        df_nav.join(df_dvd).fillna(0).rename_axis({'payout_per_share': 'dividend'}, axis=1), column='nav')
return df_nav_adj

def json_total_return_table(request, fund_account_id):
ts_list = []
for fund_id in Fund.objects.get_fund_series(fund_account_id=fund_account_id):
    if NAV.objects.filter(fund__id=fund_id, income_payable__lt=0).exists():
        ts = NAV.objects.get_adj_nav(fund_id)['adj_nav']
        ts.name = Fund.objects.get(id=fund_id).account_class_description
        ts_list.append(ts.copy())
        print(ts)
    df_adj_nav = pd.concat(ts_list, axis=1) # ====> Throws error
    cols_to_datetime(df_adj_nav, 'index')
    df_adj_nav = ffn.core.calc_stats(df_adj_nav.dropna()).to_csv(sep=',')
```

Comment: Can you paste some of your code?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sure and done

Comment: @anderish I think you answered your own question.  Since you're concatenating along axis=1 (adding more columns), then you'll want to keep the "column" lengths the same.  If that criteria isn't in place the concat feature wouldn't know how to fill in missing data.  Another pattern that you might want to consider is `merge()` [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

So I think I was correct when I said the reason why it is failing is due to difference in size. So I used `merge` instead.
I simply changed this line: `df_adj_nav = pd.concat(ts_list, axis=1)`

to this line: `df_adj_nav = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer'), ts_list)`.

Thanks to @HodgePodge for the hint :)